# How to reference a .dll File inside Customization Project Browser

Tags: acumatica

is it possible in acumatica to read the namespace inside the DLL file created by the Visual Studio with the Code File also inside Customization Project Browser.

[image: Customization Project Browser]

I have `namespace SomeCustomNameSpace` and inside it, it has a DAC of ISCustomizationSetup, I have both running Code File inside Customization Project Browser. but when it is on DAC Extension, it does not support, I tried also modifying the App_RuntimeCode generated by the Acumatica on DAC Extension to include my own `namespace`

What do I need to do?, or do I need to send all my objects inside the DLL Extension File?

Comment: I think in your case you just need the full namespace to your DAC. So use Namespace.SomeCustomNamespace.ISCustomizationSetup vs just ISCustomizationSetup

Comment: I just converted it to a code instead of under the DATA ACCESS group. It's okay now

Comment: It would be good to confirm and answer your own question if you could. I know in past experience you just need to include the full name (include namespace) when editing fields such as a user field as you have in your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the question right since my answer is very straightforward. Have you tried adding dll into [Files](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(8))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d474f5d8-47a0-42b3-af00-8e0940e32b7f) section of the customization project?
[image]

Comment: That is some big customization, yes I added it

Comment: the screen shot is the manufacturing customization - for reference